# OpenNetCF WebRequestMethod Class is missing

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, webrequest, opennetcf

I Have downloaded community edition of OpenNETCF from this [link](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx), And Trying to access FTP. But I am not able to find WebRequestMethods class in OpenNETCF.Net or OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp Namespace. Please help and suggest if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenNETCF namespaces don't have the WebRequestmethods.Ftp items.  They are simply constant strings, so you could easily create them something like this:

```
public static class WebRequestMethods
{
    public const string ListDirectoryDetails = "LIST";
    public const string DownloadFile = "RETR";
    // etc.
}
```